# Почему не работает сортировка heap sort через итераторы?

Tags: c++, сортировка, heap

Не работает сортировка Heap sort с использованием итераторов(обобщенный алгоритм). Она сортирует элементы корректно раз в несколько запусков, в остальных случаях, если брать,например, 5 элементов, то корректно отсортирует 2,3, 4 элементы, а 1 и 5 перепутает местами. Не понимаю, где ошибка в коде.

```
template<typename  Iterator>
void adjust_heap(Iterator first
                  , typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::difference_type current
                  , typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::difference_type size
                  , typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::value_type tmp )
{
    typedef typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::difference_type diff_t;

    diff_t top = current, next = 2 * current + 2;

    for ( ; next < size; current = next, next = 2 * next + 2 )
    {
        if ( *(first + next) < *(first + next - 1) )
            --next;
        *(first + current) = *(first + next);
    }

    if ( next == size )
        *(first + current) = *(first + size - 1), current = size - 1;

    for ( next = (current - 1) / 2;
          top > current && *(first + next) < tmp;
          current = next, next = (current - 1) / 2 )
    {
        *(first + current) = *(first + next);
    }
    *(first + current) = tmp;
}

template <class Iterator>
void pop_heapp( Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    typedef typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::value_type value_t;

    value_t tmp = *--last;
    *last = *first;
    adjust_heap( first, 0, last - first, tmp );
}

template <class Iterator>
void heapSort3( Iterator first, Iterator last )
{
    typedef typename  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::difference_type diff_t;
    for ( diff_t current = (last - first) / 2 - 1; current >= 0; --current )
        adjust_heap( first, current, last - first, *(first + current) );

    while ( first < last )
        pop_heapp( first, last-- );
}
```

Comment: сначала нужно хорошо представлять что такое  std::iterator_traits< Iterator >::difference_type. а после вы поймете какие ошибки допустили

Comment: Ммм,спасибо за великодушный ответ! Вы мне так помогли.

Comment: Я не смогу помочь, так как вы пишете про  heapp,  а чтобы получить кучу, нужна реализация дерева, и  имея дело чисто с итераторами, нужно задавать не  размер, а    итераторы (первый, последный, текущий...)